# Visual Studio MVC Debug and Azure Deploy different login database

Tags: database, azure, authentication, visual-studio-debugging

I have a database on azure and made a project with connection string to it. The project works when debugging and deployed to azure but the database is a bit different. Any tables I made and updated are the same on both but user tables are not. If I register user abc on debug, it won't show up on deployed and if I register user def on deploy it won't show up on debug.

Comment: Are you using the same connection string for both the Local version and the Azure deployed version?